# Error: EACCES: permission denied in project that created by Vue Cli

Tags: macos, vue.js, vuejs3, apple-m1, vue-cli

I get `Error: EACCES: permission denied` for each changes when I create a project with `vue create` command. I install Vue Cli with `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli` command.
my system information:
macbook m1
macOS ventura 13.3.1 (a)
package version:
node: v18.16.0
npm: 9.5.1
vue: @vue/cli 5.0.8
also I try create project with `sudo vue create` command but the problem still exists.

I try this [solution](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) by npmjs document and vue cli installed without sudo but after installation, vue command didn't found (work) in terminal. for example when I test `vue --version` and get `zsh: command not found: vue`.

---

**Solved: use yarn instead of npm**

Comment: Does this only occur only during you create the project or while during serving ? Have you tried "sudo" on npm run serve (or npm run dev on vite)?

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when you don't have the necessary permissions to create files or modify directories. Running commands with sudo temporarily elevates your privileges, but it's generally not recommended for global installations like Vue-cli.

To address the issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Uninstall the global Vue CLI package (if it was installed with sudo) by running: `sudo npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`
2. Clear the npm cache by running: `npm cache clean --force`
3. Set the npm global prefix to a directory that you have write permissions for (e.g., your user's home directory): `npm config set prefix ~/npm`
4. Add the new npm global bin directory to your system's PATH by adding the following line to your shell profile file (e.g., ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, or ~/.profile): `export PATH="$HOME/npm/bin:$PATH"`
5. Close and reopen your terminal
6. Install Vue CLI again without using sudo: `npm install -g @vue/cli`
   After executing the above steps, you should be able to use the vue command without encountering permission errors.

Comment: unfortunately vue cli cant installed because the installation stopped and dose not continue

Comment: what's the error that you are seeing?

Comment: Vue command didn't work. After fixing this problem, the Vue project couldn't be created without using sudo.
Finally, I used yarn and my problem was solved.